# How to display Image ( "content-disposition": "attachment" ) in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The issue is that Image URI is downloadable file.So It needed to cache it first in order to work.
because `<Image/>`  won't show any downloadable image file.

"content-disposition": "attachment"
"content-type": "image/jpeg"

```
      <Image
        style={{width: 300, height: 300}}
        source={{
          uri:
            'https://graph.facebook.com/2461177814122***/picture??height=512&width=512&type=large',
        }}
      />
```

So how to display image without cache it first.

Comment: I dont think you need content disposition property to show this type of image, i didn't had any problems showing this kind of image